# Neural Networks and correlation between input and output

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, neural-network, correlation

I am trying to fit some input to predict an output in Matlab using fitnet neural networks, but I am concerned in finding which input candidate vector would correlate the most with the output as a preprocessing step prior to my neural network training.

In the figure below the output in yellow has five input candidates where I need to chose only from. What command should I use in Matlab and how should I prepare that data (repeated around 1000 time) so I can get a clear correlation between the input candidate and the output.

[image: input candidates]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To find out correlation between given feature and target variable you can use `R = corrcoef(A,B)`, but... **do not do it!**.

This process makes **no sense** and will be probably **harmfull** for the whole process. You are going to remove part of information from your data so only features which have idependent, linear realtion to target variable persist. Then, you will apply highly-non linear model which exploits co-occurences and features correlations. These two steps are completely **incompatible**. The only valid relation is - if your data is very **simple** and it can be pretty much modeled with linear model, then neural net will work as well. But then there is no point in using a neural net in the first place, just apply linear regression. Consequently: **do not perform feature selection** unless you **have to**. Try to build a good model without doing that, and if you have to remove some features (maybe getting them is expensive process?) use post-hoc model analysis to remove features which are not used **by this model**. Do not split your problem to multiple, independent processes if you do not have to (unless you can show that this decomposition does not harm the process, but in case of feature selection + regressor this is not true, as you cannot construct a valid feature selection supervision without trained regressor).

Comment: My main concern, is that I need to find which candidate input vector works the most because there is a delay between each input vector and the output. I should choose the delay that corresponds to the mostly related input vector to the output. By trial and error, and trying each vector candidate for my neural network, the latter gave different results. But still i need a more sophisticated way to achieve that.

Comment: As said in the answer - you should never do it **independently**, as this is a property of the model used, not "general thing". Consequently you can choose most important features **for a particular network**, thus it has to be trained as well. In particular - whatever subset you will choose **it will be only reasonable** for **this network**. There is no such thing as "in general, best features". Just keep this in mind. For small features sets "trial and error" is actually a very good method, which can be easily mathematically justified.